# Compile cython extension with waf in development mode

Tags: cython, waf

Here is a simple Cython package:

```
foo/
    __init__.py # Contains:  from . import foo
    foo.pyx
```

I use `waf` (I know `pyximport` or `setup.py` can be used too) to build the Python extension from `foo.pyx`:

```
foo/
    __init__.py # Contains:  from . import foo
    foo.pyx

build/
    foo/
         foo.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I would like to import the `foo` package without installing it (development mode).

If the Python extension would be next to `__init___` like this:

```
foo/
    __init__.py # Contains:  from . import foo
    foo.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

it would work, but `__init__.py` is in the the source directory while the `.so` file is in the build directory.

I would like to avoid copying `.so` files in source directory.

A solution solution would be to copy (with waf) `foo/__init__.py` in `build/foo/__init__.py`, and import the `foo` package in `build/`.

Is there other alternatives?

Source code is [here](https://github.com/dfroger/issue/tree/a4d69279456de09f03e5798250d8ea94964501a2/cython_waf_devel_mode).